# Exiting void loop() in Arduino to stop DC motor

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to exit the `void loop()` after an if statement within the loop returns true. In other words, if the condition for the if statement is met, I want it to only run once and stop fully. This is used to control a DC motor with a potentiometer. So, as the potentiometer is HIGH, the dc motor should run for 1 second and stop fully and as the potentiometer is LOW the motor should run backward and stop fully. I'm having trouble exiting the loop.

Below is my code:

```cpp
const int potIn = A0;
const int actIn = A1;
const int outA = 3;
const int outB = 11;

int potInput = 0;
int actInput = 0;
int outputValue = 0;
int potAnalog = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:


    pinMode(potIn, INPUT);
    pinMode(actIn, INPUT);
    pinMode(outA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(outB, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
    //  put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    potInput = digitalRead(potIn);
    actInput = analogRead(actIn);
    potAnalog = analogRead(potIn);


    if (potInput == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(outA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(outB, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(outA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(outB, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(i == 1)
                break;
        }
    }


    if (potInput == LOW){
        digitalWrite(outA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(outB, LOW);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear - *which* `if` statement within the loop? Which loop? The function named `loop` or a loop within `loop`?

Comment: The function named loop. The first if statement within void loop ()

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { if(i == 1) break; }` does not seem to serve any useful purpose. The `break` exits the `for` loop. If you return from the `void` loop it will be called again.

Comment: It's a function. If you want to 'leave' it, just 'return;'

Comment: @Weather Vane how do I use the break command to execute that if statement then?

Answer (score 1):

adding the statement
exit(0);
at the end, works for me!

Answer (score -1):

delete the void loop and use int main() with while(true) inside....you can now exit from the while whenever you want

Comment: can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score -1):

you can write your code into an int main() function instead of void loop(). void loop() is simply a function where the statement is:
while (true) {
}
so you have this solution:

Delete void loop and write a while (flag==true){ } where you have to write your code (your void loop code) inside the braces and simply set flag to false when you have to exit from the loop.

Comment: what is flag in this context? So I delete the void loop() and replace it with a while loop? so like: while (potInput == HIGH){if statement}
but how do I exit the while loop

Comment: This is Arduino code. You can't just delete the `loop()` function and define `main()`. And don't make multiple same answers.

Comment: you can delete all and define main with flag true.